# how to get access to all my enemy nodes at the same time

Tags: sprite-kit, arc4random

I have 6 sprites of enemies in SpriteKit game.  I want to have access to all of them like "enemies" in order to make them appear on scene in the random order. I tried to do this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var redBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBox")
var greenBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenBox")
var blueBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueBox")
var magentaBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "magentaBox")
var cyanBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cyanBox")
var yellowBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellowBox")

func randomBox() -> SKSpriteNode {

    let boxes = [redBox, greenBox, blueBox, magentaBox, cyanBox, yellowBox]
    let count = boxes.count
    var randomOne = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
    var randomBox = boxes[randomOne]

    return randomBox
}

var oneBox: SKSpriteNode = randomBox()
}
```

But in oneBox Xcode gives me an error and says "missing parameter #1 in call".

How to pick a random node the right way?

EDIT: my code that causing that error:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
//boxes
var redBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBox")
var greenBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenBox")
var blueBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueBox")
var magentaBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "magentaBox")
var cyanBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cyanBox")
var yellowBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellowBox")
var oneBox:SKSpriteNode!


func randomBox() -> SKSpriteNode {

    let boxes = [redBox, greenBox, blueBox, magentaBox, cyanBox, yellowBox]
    let count = boxes.count
    var randomOne = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
    var randomBox = boxes[randomOne]

    return randomBox
}

//random for Y
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var oneBox: SKSpriteNode = randomBox()

    func addUpperBoxes() {
let middleY = random(min: size.height/2, max: size.height - size.height/3)
oneBox.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + oneBox.size.width/2, y: middleY)
addChild(oneBox)
let middleDuration = random(min: CGFloat(1.5), max: CGFloat(2.5))

let middleMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -oneBox.size.width/2, y: middleY), duration: NSTimeInterval(middleDuration))
let middleMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
oneBox.runAction(SKAction.sequence([middleMove, middleMoveDone]))
    }

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addUpperBoxes),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
            ])
        ))
}
```

Comment: You need to move the `oneBox = ...` statement in a method such as `didMoveToView` or `touchesBegan`.

Comment: So there is no option to make oneBox accessible in every part of the game? What if I put it in `didMoveToView` and will need it in `Update?`

Comment: Define it after `var yellow...` as `var oneBox:SKSpriteNode!` and then initialize it in `didMoveToView`. You can then access it in `update`.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much! One more question: if I'm accessing those nodes through oneBox, do I still need to  do `self.addChild(yellowBox); self.addChild(redBox)` etc. or adding `addChild(oneBox)` will be enough?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Obviously, `addChild` will add the boxes to the scene, so you should add them only when you need them in the game. You can add the box with `oneBox` but make sure you add a box only once or the app will crash.

Comment: That's what happened to me a second ago. I tried to make a line of random boxes moving from the right bound to the left, one after another. App crashed and I got an error `Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'cyanBox' (50 x 50)]`, But I don't understand why, I only did `addChild(oneBox)`.

Comment: You will need to come up with a way to prevent a box that was already selected from being selected again.

Comment: So I can't have 2 or more same nodes on scene at the same time? It's strange but that error told me about one box, but there was another box on the screen

Comment: Maybe you should create a new `SKSpriteNode` instance in randomBox and assign the node a random color. Then you can have multiple boxes in the scene with the same color.

Comment: I don't understand, it's not working! All I want is to choose a random node and make it move, how hard can it be? I've found [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605491/choosing-random-image-for-skspritenode) on the same problem, tried to implement it and failed with the same error.